# Android TabLayout Scroll Selected tab to the left

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I would like to always left align `TabLayout.Tab` when they are selected. Currently, the selected tab gets aligned in the middle. How can I achieve this?

Also, how to get relative position of tab that is visible? For ex, the tab that I selected is visible and is left most in the TabLayout. Relative position should be 0 for this tab.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you want the positions of the tabs to change so that whatever is selected will move the leftmost spot and the others will move to the right?

Comment: Yes, I meant that the TabLayout should scroll to the left so that selected tab is always the leftmost tab.

Comment: I'm still not clear and now you are including the word "scroll". Do you want only the tabs, only the content, or both to move to the left? Do you want things to animate in a certain way when you say scroll? Please explain in a little more detail what you want to happen when you select a tab. Maybe provide a picture.